# Pyspark SQL SHA1 encryption conversion to bigint

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need bigint version of sha1 encrypted text. This is the sha1 converted ouputed,

```
select upper(sha1('THIsneedstobeChanges'))

output

upper(sha1(CAST(THIsneedstobeChanges AS BINARY)))

0BF3770DF2705F6318491A955D32666395810537
```

So now I need to convert it to bigint

```
select cast(upper(sha1('THIsneedstobeChanges')) as bigint)

Output is null.
```

Basically I am trying to replicate this code from SQL to spark -SQL,

```
select cast(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'testdata') as bigint)
```

Could you please help with this issue

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Thanks a lot for replying. So my requirement is to get the text, convert it to sha1 and then to bigint. I am trying to replicate a function from SQL to spark SQL,

SQL code, 

select cast(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'testdata') as bigint)

The reason to mention it under Spark SQL is because the hashbyte function is used in SQL environment, which is not there in Spark SQL

Comment: So you're specifically converting from T-SQL then, I think (the dialect used by Microsoft SQL Server). This is important to know for the behavior, in several respects, because converting a string to binary depends on the collation used, and you'd need to know that casting a `VARBINARY` to a `BIGINT` works by taking the 8 least significant bytes. (I have no idea how to write that in Spark SQL, but someone who knows Spark SQL might, as long as they know how T-SQL does it.) This is assuming you need to get the *exact same value* as in T-SQL, rather than just "a truncated hash", which is easier.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yes specifically converting from T-SQL. So how does this work in microsft sql server, if you can give some insight, it will be really helpful. so hashbyte converts the string to varbinary and then to bigint how does that happen?

Comment: [Like so](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4cb19e32f6a1b4ad6c541083b33871b9).

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeroenMostert, but I might still need help for Spark-SQL conversion

Comment: Also is there anything similar to hashbytes in spark-sql

Comment: Did you get a answer for this question

Comment: @SnehaNair , Did you find out the solution of converting sha(str) to BIG INT in Spark sql